# SQL, print the amount for each model

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm haven't enough experience in construction of SQL-query yet.
I have a 2 table:

---

```
producers ( 
    prod_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    prod_title text
); 

models ( 
    prod_id NOT NULL, 
    model_name text, 
    FOREIGN KEY (prod_id) REFERENCES producers(prod_id)
);
```

---

How do I get a table of the form:

```
column1.............column2 

producer1...........the amount of models producers1

producer2...........the amount of models producers2

...

producerN...........the amount of models producerN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description of the tables it looks like you want to use the `count` function, and group by the producer id, so try this:

```
select p.prod_title, count(*) 
from producers p
join models m on p.prod_id = m.prod_id
group by p.prod_id
```